# React app using json server, unable to render data from server

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, json-server

I am trying to fetch some data with useEffect from json server but I am having the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'questionText'). I was able to display the data before replicating data base with json server. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const QuestionSection = () => {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    const [showScore, setShowScore] = useState(false);
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getQuestions = async () => {
            const questionsFromServer = await fetchQuestions()
            setQuestions(questionsFromServer)
        }

        getQuestions()
    }, [])
    //Fetch questions 
    const fetchQuestions = async () => {
        const res = await fetch ('http://localhost:5000/questions');
        const data = await res.json();
        
        return data 
    }
    

    const handleAnswerOptionClick = (correct) => {
        if (correct) {
            setScore(score + 1);

        }

        const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        if (nextQuestion < questions.length) {
            setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
        } else {
            setShowScore(true);
        }
    };
  return (
    <questionSection>
    <div className='questionSection'>
            {showScore ? (
                <div className='score-section'>
                    You scored {score} out of {questions.length}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <div className='question-section'>
                        <div className='question-count'>
                            <span>Question {currentQuestion + 1}</span>/{questions.length}
                        </div>
                        <div className='question-text'>{questions[currentQuestion].questionText}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='answer-section'>
                        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
                            <button key = {answerOption.id} onClick={() => handleAnswerOptionClick(answerOption.correct)}>{answerOption.answerLetter} {answerOption.answerText}</button>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    </questionSection>
  )
}

export default QuestionSection
```

Answer (score 0):

Since fetching the questions is an asynchronous action, you have to handle the undefined situation in your code.
An easy fix is to add the `?` before the questionText property:

```
<div className='question-text'>{questions[currentQuestion]?.questionText}</div>
```

The question mark checks if the `currentQuestion` exists in the questions array, if it does the `questionText` is displayed.

Comment: Thank you. The optional chaining solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Initially the array is empty, and doing `` will give you `undefined`. Which is what the error says. This situation will happen until the API call is made and resolved.
Depending on your preference you can show different UI based on this. For example below code shows `Fetching questions` for some time:

```
 <questionSection>
    <div className='questionSection'>
            {showScore  ? (
                <div className='score-section'>
                    You scored {score} out of {questions.length}
                </div>
            ) : (
                questions.length > 0 ? <>
                    <div className='question-section'>
                        <div className='question-count'>
                            <span>Question {currentQuestion + 1}</span>/{questions.length}
                        </div>
                        <div className='question-text'>{questions[currentQuestion].questionText}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='answer-section'>
                        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
                            <button key = {answerOption.id} onClick={() => handleAnswerOptionClick(answerOption.correct)}>{answerOption.answerLetter} {answerOption.answerText}</button>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </> : <p>Fetching Questions</p>
            )}
        </div>
    </questionSection>
```